# Proving that a topological space is not metrizable

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

Given $X = \{p,q\}$ with topology given by $\emptyset, \{p\}, X$, I am trying to prove that $X$ is not metrizable. The lecture notes that I am working through do not introduce the Hausdorff property until much later, which leads me to believe that there is some other way to prove it. However, this is the only way I can think to establish it.

I'm taking for granted that a metric topology is Hausdorff. Therefore, if a space is not Hausdorff, it is not metrizable. We have two distinct points $p,q$, but I cannot find disjoint open sets, one containing $p$ and one containing $q$, because $\{q\}$ is not open.  In particular, any open set containing $q$ must also contain $p$, so the space isn't Hausdorff and is hence not metrizable.

Is this logic correct?  Is there a way to prove this fact without appealing to the Hausdorff property?

Comment: I would like to add that your space is called Sierpinski Space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument is fine.

You can do this in a more direct way. Assume there is a metric $d$ on your $X$. Let $r=d(p,q)>0$. Then the open ball around $q$ of radius $r$ is precisely $\{q\}$. And so $q$ has to be open. Contradiction.

Similar argument shows that any finite metric space has to be discrete (i.e. every point has to be open).